# Grafana MySQL isn't using the given password

Tags: mysql, authentication, grafana

I'm trying to use [Grafana MySQL](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/datasources/mysql/) to gather metrics on my database.

However, I cannot access the database from the plugin even if I can from MySQL Workbench or Datagrip.

My configuration is the following:

```yaml
  - name: MySQL
    type: mysql
    URL: <my_host>:3306
    database: csc648
    user: <user>
    isDefault: false
    secureJsonData:
      password: "<my_password>"
    jsonData:
      maxOpenConns: 0         # Grafana v5.4+
      maxIdleConns: 2         # Grafana v5.4+
      connMaxLifetime: 14400  # Grafana v5.4+
```

I created a special user with only read access. This user works but not with the plugin.

Here's the request I used

```sql
CREATE USER '<user>'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '<my_password>';

GRANT SELECT ON <database>.* TO '<user>'@'%';

FLUSH PRIVILEGES;

SHOW GRANTS FOR '<user>'@'%';
```

The error thrown by the UI is

```
db query error: query failed - please inspect Grafana server log for details
```

And when I look at the log I see the following error

```
Error 1045: Access denied for user '<my_user>'@'<host>' (using password: NO)"
```

I do not understand why it says `using password: NO` since I provide one.
I get the same error if I try from the UI too...

I'm using `grafana/grafana:9.3.6` docker image.

Comment: I'm currently having this problem - did you figure out the solution?

Comment: I figured it out. I was using an environment variable for password, but it turns out that variable wasn't being set as I expected, so it was blank, and password was NO

Comment: I'm not using any environment variable on this example, but if you could find a way to make it works and monitor your database, I would love that you share an example as solution.

Comment: Here are the differences I see with my config and yours: database should be in jsonData instead of outside, url should be lowercase, secureJsonData should be after jsonData, there should be no quotation marks outside the password. I kind of doubt changing these will fix that error message, but try!